# How do I write a script that opens an iTerm2 window and runs a command?

Tags: terminal, applescript, script, iterm

### What I'm doing

I'm using iTerm2 Build 3.0.15 and writing a script that opens a new window and prints "hello world" to the screen. Really, I'm interested in being to run any command but using `echo "hello world"` as a starting point.

### What I've tried

I read up on the iTerm2 [documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html) for scripting. I wanted to learn more so I dragged the `iTerm2` icon on the `Script Editor` icon to view the dictionary available to me and found the following command:

[image]

From reading the dictionary and documentation I wrote the following script:

```
tell application "iTerm"
  create window with default profile command "echo hello world"
end tell
```

When I run my script from the terminal a new window opened and "hello world" was on the screen; however, I got the following broken pipe error:
[image]

When I select `Ok` the window closed and I'm left with the following message:

```
$ osascript iterm.applescript
window id 6415
```

### The Questions

- What do these broken pipe and window id 6415 errors mean?
- How do I write a script that opens an iTerm2 window and runs a command?

Comment: delay 1
write text "clear"
is nice if you want a clean start

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
tell application "iTerm2"
    set newWindow to (create window with default profile)
    tell current session of newWindow
        write text "echo it works!"
    end tell
end tell
```

The `write` *command*, when not using `without newline`, executes the `write text` *command* because of the default added *newline* after the "text to send". Thus the window stays open after the *command* completes, ready for additional use.

---

From the iTerm AppleScript Dictionary:

> **write** *v* : Send text as though it was typed.
>
> **write** specifier : The session to send to
>               [**contents of file** file] : Filename to send the contents of
>               [**text** text] : Text to send
>               [**newline** boolean] : If newline should be added to end of text (default: yes)

Comment: This used to work when running it with `osascript -e`, but recently started giving me error `-2741`: Syntax error, "," expected, but classname found. (Translated error-message from German, English wording might be slightly different).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `command "echo hello world"` with

```
command "bash -c \"echo hello world && read\""
```

The use of `read` makes bash wait for the user to end the line (i.e. by pressing enter) before exiting. Pressing enter within 3 seconds will still yield the warning, as this is an iTerm feature which you can disable by checking the box on the alert, and control more precisely in Preferences → Advanced → Warn about short-lived sessions.

Comment: @user Sure, edited

Comment: Is it possible to not have the terminal close? The goal is to be able to say "Open iTerm run this command and don't quit"

Answer (score -2):

```
on alfred_script(q)
    tell application "iTerm2"
        set newWindow to (create window with default profile)
        tell current session of newWindow
            write text q
        end tell
    end tell
end alfred_script
```

Comment: We are looking for answers which are more than just a code snippet. What does this script do, how can it be used, how does it differ from the similar-looking one in one of the other answers, and who is Alfred? Please edit your answer to add details.